# Make wcf client wait for the callback

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm currently working on a project, where I have to manage an application via a wcf client. The problem I'm facing is that after making a call to the server I need the client to wait for the callback to be made. Here is the scenario:

I make a call to the service which shows a window and then the server app is idle. When i click a button on the window, it makes a callback to the client. during the time, the client UI has to be disabled - it has to wait for the callback. Could you please tell me how I can achieve this? Does it have something to do with Concurrency Mode or the Operation Contract attribute?

This is my code for the ServiceContract and the CallbackContract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IWCFServiceCallback))]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void OpenWindow();
}
public interface IWCFServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReturnValue(object[] value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I solved the problem by using the Win32 ShowWindow function.

Answer (score 1):

No, the feature you describe has nothing to do with Concurrency Mode or the Operation Contract. You probably need to implement the feature using semaphores (`Mutex`, `Monitor`, whatever ...) and callbacks from server to client to set the semaphore.

Having said that the functionality you describe seems really odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing an asynchronous service operation and calling it using `Async/Await`.

Disable your client UI just before calling your service, and then enable it after the callback returns.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Microsoft.WCF.Documentation
{
  [ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://microsoft.wcf.documentation")]
  public interface ISampleService{

    [OperationContractAttribute]
    string SampleMethod(string msg);

    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSampleMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    //Note: There is no OperationContractAttribute for the end method.
    string EndSampleMethod(IAsyncResult result);

    [OperationContractAttribute(AsyncPattern=true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginServiceAsyncMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

    // Note: There is no OperationContractAttribute for the end method.
    string EndServiceAsyncMethod(IAsyncResult result);
  }

  public class SampleService : ISampleService
  {
    #region ISampleService Members

    public string  SampleMethod(string msg)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Called synchronous sample method with \"{0}\"", msg);
      return "The sychronous service greets you: " + msg;
    }

    // This asynchronously implemented operation is never called because 
    // there is a synchronous version of the same method.
    public IAsyncResult BeginSampleMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BeginSampleMethod called with: " + msg);
      return new CompletedAsyncResult<string>(msg);
    }

    public string EndSampleMethod(IAsyncResult r)
    {
      CompletedAsyncResult<string> result = r as CompletedAsyncResult<string>;
      Console.WriteLine("EndSampleMethod called with: " + result.Data);
      return result.Data;
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginServiceAsyncMethod(string msg, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine("BeginServiceAsyncMethod called with: \"{0}\"", msg);
      return new CompletedAsyncResult<string>(msg);
    }

    public string EndServiceAsyncMethod(IAsyncResult r)
    {
      CompletedAsyncResult<string> result = r as CompletedAsyncResult<string>;
      Console.WriteLine("EndServiceAsyncMethod called with: \"{0}\"", result.Data);
      return result.Data;
    }
    #endregion
  }

  // Simple async result implementation.
  class CompletedAsyncResult<T> : IAsyncResult
  {
    T data;

    public CompletedAsyncResult(T data)
    { this.data = data; }

    public T Data
    { get { return data; } }

    #region IAsyncResult Members
    public object AsyncState
    { get { return (object)data; } }

    public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
    { get { throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented."); } }

    public bool CompletedSynchronously
    { get { return true; } }

    public bool IsCompleted
    { get { return true; } }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will just add that after calling a method I want the client to act same as if the method itself was returning the value (without a callback) - the client waits untill the service completes its work and returns a value. I can't lock the UI manually because the client is an Excel addin, which has no forms/windows which I could disable.

Comment: The call to the service is made while Excel has a FunctionWizard open, so I can't just lock the cells because it makes Excel crash.

Comment: @Bartek — That's a different problem, then, for a separate Q&A. I believe I've provided the answer to this question, but if not let me know and I'll try to help further. FYI note that Microsoft in its sample code here has strayed from its own [recommended naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx#Anchor_7). Asynchronous functions should have 'Async' appended to their names. Granted we don't see the `async` keyword here, but this is an asynchronous architecture nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

When the concurrenymode is ConcurrencyMode.Single and the client calls the service, the service will create a lock. When it calls the callback interface with IsOneWay is false a result message will be sent back to the service. The service will create the lock again and will deadlock because the lock is held from the client call still. 
With ConsurrencyMode. Reentrant the lock will sneakily be released when calling back and reacquired on return so you could use that.
IsOneWay=true is also a solution as no result message is sent back the service calling back.

So you should be able to lock you GUI just before calling the service and unlock it in the callback when the callback operation has IsOneWay = true or the service has ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant configured

Comment: The problem is that I cannot lock the UI of the client manually, as it is an Excel AddIn with a FunctionWizard open. If I try locking the cells, Excel crashes.